# How to get Applescript input to run Terminal Command

Tags: macos, applescript

I am frequently switching between school computers and have a preference to have the hidden files shown, however, not everyone does. Normally I use the

`"defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true"`

command, however, it would be very convenient if I could just run some Applescript, instead of manually copying the text into the Terminal and then redoing this when I'm done. So what I am trying to accomplish is the receive user input as to whether they want to show all files or not and then run that command. Doing some initial research on Applescript I was able to figure out some basic idea of how I would structure it. The below code is wrong, so please excuse by noob mistakes.

```
(choose from list {"Hide", "Show"} ¬
    with prompt "Do you want to hide or show hidden files?")
if "Hide" then
    do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool False"
else 
    do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool True"
end
```

I can get up to the user dialogue box, however, when I try and input a choice, it replies: "Can’t make "Hide" into type boolean.". If someone could help me out show me what I need to change then that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Michael.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`choose from list` returns a list of the selected items.

```
choose from list {"Hide", "Show"} with prompt "Do you want to hide or show hidden files?"
if result is {"Show"} then
    do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true"
else
    do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool false"
end if
quit application "Finder"
```

I use a script like this to toggle showing hidden files:

```
do shell script "x=$(defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles)
[ $x = 1 ] && b=false || b=true
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool $b"
tell application "Finder"
    quit
    delay 0.1 -- without this delay Finder was not made frontmost
    launch -- open Finder in the background
    delay 0.1 -- without this delay there was sometimes a "connection is invalid" error
    activate -- make Finder frontmost
    reopen -- open a new default window
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the hasty response, the changes you made to my code seem to work quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Choose from list returns a list (or False if the user cancels). Do this to coerce the list into a string:

```
(choose from list {"Hide", "Show"} ¬
    with prompt "Do you want to hide or show hidden files?") as string
```

Make sure you keep the parentheses, otherwise, `as string` will coerce your prompt string, and you will still receive a list back.